# How do I cast an object to a dynamic type?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

All of my objects are composed from a base abstract class called `GameObject`.  All of these objects inherit from one or more interfaces, such as `IRenderable`, `IAnimatable`, `IMovable`, etc.

I also have a list of these objects stored as `List<GameObject>`.  I'm trying to write a dynamic method that will return to me all of the objects that has inherited from a specific interface, like so:

```
List<IRenderable> renderableObjects = ObjectManager.GetAll<IRenderable>();
```

At first, I tried just returning a new list of game objects where each object's type matches the dynamic type, then casting the `List<GameObject>` to `List<T>`.  The compiler error I received said that I could not convert those types.

So my second attempt involved casting each object individually, as shown below.

```
public List<T> GetAll<T>() {
    List<T> list = new List<T>();

    foreach( GameObject obj in this.gameObjects )
        if( obj is T )
            list.Add( (T)obj );

     return list;
}
```

However, this throws the same type of error; cannot convert type GameObject to T.  Am I missing something?  Is there another way to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LINQ already has a nice handy method for you, `OfType()`.

```
List<GameObject> list = ...;
var movableObjects = list.OfType<IMovable>();
```

`OfType` will return a sequence with all of the items from the input sequence that can be cast to the type you specified.  Additionally there is the `Cast<T>()` operator which just tried to cast everything and will throw an exception if an item can't be cast (which doesn't appear to be what you want here).

Answer (score 4):

Servy has given a better approach, but you can fix your code easily too. Just give the `T` generic type parameter a constraint:

```
public List<T> GetAll<T>() where T : GameObject {
```

Another (nastier) alternative is to add an extra cast:

```
list.Add((T)(object)obj);
```

Conversions to a generic type parameter are a bit messy. See [Eric Lippert's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/07/10/when-is-a-cast-not-a-cast.aspx?PageIndex=2) for more details.

(I'd definitely use Servy's approach - there's no point in reinventing the wheel - I just wanted to explain how to fix your code in similar situations.)